# General description for the $n$-th derivative of $e^{-1/x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, power-series

I am self-learning Real Analysis from the text, *Understanding Analysis*, by Stephen Abbott. The exercise problem 6.6.6 asks to prove certain stylized facts about the piecewise defined function:

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}, & x \neq 0 \\ 0, & x = 0 \end{cases}$$

Do you have clue/hint (without giving away the entire solution) for part (b) of this problem.

> [Abbott 6.6.6] Review the proof that $\displaystyle g'( 0) =0$.
>
> (a) Compute $\displaystyle g'( x)$ for $\displaystyle x\neq 0$. Then use the definition of the derivative to find $\displaystyle g''( 0)$.
>
> (b)  Compute $\displaystyle g''( x)$ and $\displaystyle g'''( x)$ for $\displaystyle x\neq 0$. Use these observations and invent whatever notation is needed to give a general description for the $\displaystyle n$th derivative $\displaystyle g^{( n)}( x)$ at points different from zero.

***Proof.***

(a) We have:

\begin{equation*}
g'( x) =\frac{2}{x^{3}} e^{-1/x^{2}}
\end{equation*}

By definition,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ c l c }
g''( 0) & =\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g'( x) -g'( 0)}{x-0} & \\
 & =\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{g'( x)}{x} & \\
 & =\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{1}{x^{4}}}{e^{1/x^{2}}} & \\
 & =\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^{3} \cdot \left( -4/x^{5}\right)}{\left( -2e^{1/x^{2}}\right)} & \left\{\text{L'Hospital's rule} ,\infty /\infty \right\}\\
 & =2\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{1}{x^{2}}}{e^{1/x^{2}}} & \\
 & =2\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{-\frac{2}{x^{3}}}{-\frac{2}{x^{3}} e^{1/x^{2}}} & \left\{\text{L'Hospital's rule} ,\infty /\infty \right\}\\
 & =2\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{e^{1/x^{2}}} & \\
 & =0 & 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

(b) If $\displaystyle x\neq 0$, we have:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ c l }
g'( x) & =2e^{-1/x^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)\\
g''( x) & =2\left[\left( x^{-3}\right) '\left( e^{-1/x^{2}}\right) +\left( x^{-3}\right)\left( e^{-1/x^{2}}\right) '\right]\\
 & =2e^{-1/x^{2}}\left[ -\frac{3}{x^{4}} +\frac{2}{x^{6}}\right]\\
g'''( x) & =2\left[\left( e^{-1/x^{2}}\right) '\cdot \left( -\frac{3}{x^{4}} +\frac{2}{x^{6}}\right) +e^{-1/x^{2}}\left( -\frac{3}{x^{4}} +\frac{2}{x^{6}}\right)^{'}\right]\\
 & =2e^{-1/x^{2}}\left[\frac{2}{x^{3}}\left( -\frac{3}{x^{4}} +\frac{2}{x^{6}}\right) +\left(\frac{12}{x^{5}} -\frac{12}{x^{7}}\right)\right]\\
 & =2e^{-1/x^{2}}\left[\frac{12}{x^{5}} -\frac{12}{x^{7}} -\frac{6}{x^{7}} +\frac{4}{x^{9}}\right]
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

I can't seem to find the general expression for the $n$th derivative, $g^{(n)}(x)$.

Comment: You are not expected to have a specific formula. You are expected to observe that these coefficients are polynomials of a certain degree in $1/x$. Prove such a conjecture by induction.

Comment: The problem says "general description", not "general expression". A small difference, but a pertinent one.

Comment: If you want a formula, that you do not need, then expand $e^y$ as a sum and take the derivatives. Alternatively, use [this limit](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/09/01/0001/) to make part of it a power function